# AngularJS Long Polling View Not Updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, long-polling

I'm trying to use long polling within an angularjs app.  I have the long polling within a controller that is updating a scope variable that is referenced within the view.
When I step through the code the polling is occurring and the expected data is being returned but the view is never being updated.

longpolltest.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.value = 1;
    function poll() {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        $scope.value++;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/gs/async?millis=' + n,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) {
               var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               if (obj.type == 'ServerTime')
                   $scope.myTime = object.Data.Time;
               setTimeout("poll()", 1000);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                setTimeout("poll()", 10000);
            }
        });
    }
    poll();
 });
```

longpolltest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/ext/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- angular library -->
    <script src="js/ext/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ext/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/longpolltest.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Long poll test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <p>
            Time: {{myTime}}
            Poll#: {{value}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas why the view would not be getting updated would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to  `$scope.$apply()` wherever you update `$scope.myTime` in ajax function

Comment: You're not using angular's `$http` for ajax request, I also see there use of `setTimeout` (instead of `$timeout` / `$interval`) - The digest loop doesn't "know" about those changes so the view doesn't get changed

Comment: You are doing two things outside of the scope of angular. The first being jquery's AJAX the second being setTimeout. There is no need to use either of these, use angular `$http` and `$timeout`. the issue is these happen outside of angulars scope so it doesnt know it needs to update bindings. Are you applying angular to a jquery based app by any chance.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and feedback. I had initially had a line in there that I was fairly new to angular but I think that's pretty obvious now.  I will use the existing angular services and report back.   I was taking some existing code from a jQuery based app and trying to reuse it within this angular app.

Answer (score 1):

Some general advice:

- don't use jquery http method. You should prefer $http angular service.
- don't use timeout function.You should prefer $timeout angular service.
- don't invoke http remote services inside your controller. You should create a dedicated service.

Comment: Thanks.  This is consistent with the other advice except I will move the polling into a service.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A further improvement can be to use the $interval service